# Android password screen status

Tags: android

How do I get the status of android phone when the lockscreen start to countdown disabled lock?
I know I need some services to use this and even BroadcastListener, and I will put my condition on BroadcastListener.

Sample code:

```
if  ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction(){

}
```

is there an (android.intent.action.) too that I can get the lockscreen status?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

See the broadcast intents `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` and `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF`.

For Android 2.1 and higher you can use `isScreenOn()` of the PowerManager.